# Use response from getJson globally

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

when the page loads I want to get a json as so:

```
$.getJSON(_routes['salesInAMonthJS'], { month: "September 2016" }).then(
    function(d){
        console.log(d);
    }
);
```

this

```
$.getJSON(_routes['salesInAMonthJS'], { month: "September 2016" });
```

gives me back

```
{"9":{"name":"alex lloyd","country":"Germany","antiquity":"new client","amount":"0.0 USD"},"10":{"name"
:"asdasdsadasda dasda","country":"Afghanistan","antiquity":"new client","amount":"0.0 USD"},"11":{"name"
:"Alex Lloyd","country":"American Samoa","antiquity":"new client","amount":"0.0 USD"},"12":{"name":"alex
 lloyd","country":"Aruba","antiquity":"new client","amount":"0.0 USD"},"5":{"name":"surgeon bueno","country"
:"Spain","antiquity":"renewal","amount":"2686.97 USD"}}
```

However when a user clicks a button I want to display the data stored in `d`

for example:

```
$(document).on("click ", ".tick", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.each(d, function(i, item) {
        &("div.container").append(d[i].name);
    });
});
```

However this doesn't seem to work, any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: `&("div.container")` is a typo for `$("div.container")`.

Comment: You have a variable scope problem. `d` is local to the `$.getJSON` callback function, you can't access it in another function.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$.getJSON(geocodingAPI, function(json) {
  $.json = json;
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  alert($.json.status)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eywpvyrr/1/

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `d` is just the callback function. You can move the click binding into that so you can access it.

```
$.getJSON(_routes['salesInAMonthJS'], { month: "September 2016" }).then(function(d){
    $(document).on("click ", ".tick", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.each(d, function(i, item) {
            $("div.container").append(d[i].name);
        });
    });
});
```